# Restore a Mac to default state

Tags: macos

What is the best way to restore a new Mac (running Yosemite) to its "unused" state i.e. if you use a new mac to try it out, but have to return it to its owner, how can you make sure that any personal information (Apple ID, emails, web history, Pages Documents etc) on the Mac has been removed. I would like to do something similar to how you can delete all user data on an iPhone i.e. without having to format the disk and re-install the OS.
To be clear, I do not want to save anything from the Mac, but purely to restore it to "factory fresh" state.

Comment: how about you delete the user account (yours)

Comment: If that will remove all trace of "me" being there, that will do fine :)

Comment: Basically all "user" stuff, but if you used the admin account to install apps then they will be still there.

Comment: Thanks ... Fairly new here, so can't see how to mark this as answered.

Comment: Questions that only have comment and no answers can't be marked as answered however you can mark a comment as being useful by clicking on the triangle when you mouseover the area directly preceding the comment.  You can always ask that someones comments be posted as an answer so you can mark it more appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OSX factory reset, backup all your data, then restart your Mac and hold down Command + R key. Use Disk Utility to erase the hard drive. Click on Disk Utility > Continue. Select the main volume and click Unmount then Erase. Quit Disk Utility. Click Reinstall OS X and Continue. Follow the instructions to reinstall Mac OS X.

For IOS, go to Settings/General/Reset and select Erase All Content and Settings